401 Unauthorized Error When Connecting WinForms to Azure SignalR Service
I’m working on a WinForms application that needs to connect to an Azure SignalR Service hosted on a web app. I’m encountering a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to establish the SignalR connection.
Here is the code I’m using to initialize the SignalR connection in my WinForms app:
private async void InitializeSignalRConnection()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    try
    {
        string token = await GetSignalRAccessToken();

        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://your-signalr-endpoint/client/?hub=notifications", options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token);
            })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();
        
        connection.On<TransactionData>("SendMessageToClients", async (transactionData) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Transaction Received in WinForms: {transactionData.TransactionId}");
            await connection.InvokeAsync("AcknowledgeTransaction", transactionData.TransactionId, "Received and Processed by WinForms");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("SignalR connection started.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error initializing SignalR connection: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

Here is the relevant configuration from my web app:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("testing", policy =>
{
    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
}));

string azureSignalRConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSignalRConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(azureSignalRConnectionString);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("testing");
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notifications");
app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

What I’ve Tried:
Verified the SignalR connection URL.
Checked CORS policy settings.
Confirmed that the token is correctly generated and passed.
Expected Result:
Successful connection to the SignalR hub.
Actual Result:
401 Unauthorized error.
Any help on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

as you checked it is generating the token but could you also confirm the generated token  is valid or JWT (JSON Web Token) with the correct claims or not. could you confirm if your web app has  configured with proper authentication. .try to add some logging code to get more detail about the issue. You can enable console log. could you share your authentication part of code here how you  are handling it at both side.

Here is the link for connection inside both project. https://pastebin.com/bQXgvRGX when i try to connect to localhost hub from winform it is getting connected, but when i use azure signalr url it is giving 401

You are passing an access token, but the server-side configuration doesn't show any JWT or token validation setup in the above.
Add JWT Authentication to the Server
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add Razor Pages and other services
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("testing", policy =>
{
    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
}));

// Add JWT Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "your-issuer-url",     // Replace with your issuer URL
            ValidAudience = "your-audience",     // Replace with your audience
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your-signing-key")) // Your signing key
        };

        // Allow SignalR access token to be passed as a query string
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                // If the request is for the SignalR hub
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/notifications"))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

// Add SignalR and use Azure SignalR Service
string azureSignalRConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSignalRConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(azureSignalRConnectionString);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Build the app
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("testing");
app.UseAuthentication();  // Make sure to include this line for authentication
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notifications");
app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

NOTE: Check that the token audience (aud) claim matches the SignalR endpoint URL.
On Client-Side add logging like below:
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://your-signalr-endpoint/client/?hub=notifications", options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token);
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);  // Set to debug for detailed logs
        logging.AddConsole();
    })
    .Build();

Token Generated:

Successful Connection:
[DEBUG] - Generated Token: eyJodHRwOiJ... (a long JWT token)

[DEBUG] - Token Claims:
  iss: https://issuer-url/
  aud: https://signalr-endpoint/client/?hub=notifications
  exp: 1694997200
  sub: Suresh@example.com

[DEBUG] - Attempting to establish SignalR connection to: https://your-signalr-endpoint/client/?hub=notifications

[DEBUG] - Connection state: Connecting

[INFO] - SignalR connection started successfully.

[DEBUG] - Transaction Received in WinForms: TX12345

[DEBUG] - Acknowledging transaction TX12345: "Received and Processed by WinForms"

